# Assign a generic name to a range of cells

Tags: vba

I am trying to create a macro in VBA that assigns the name contained in a cell to a range of cells. As you can see from the picture, column “U” contains the name of the arrays that I have to create and the range of cells is from column V to column AH. Please consider that I would like to create the name of the array using the next cell in column U where there is something written in. Can you please help me in this task?

Here is the code I used:

```
Selection.End(xlDown).Select

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="FTE_Headofsecurityandrevprotection_18", _
    RefersToR1C1:="='Job Title FTEs'!R36C22:R36C34"

ActiveWorkbook.Names("FTE_Headofsecurityandrevprotection_18").Comment = "
```

Basically I would like to create a macro that assigns a name to a range of cells, using name manager. The names that name manager needs to create are in column U and the range of data that name manager needs to use are from column v to column AH. Please consider that name manager needs to be used for the next available cell in column U.

Comment: There's no picture in your question. Also you're much more likely to get an answer if you can at least make an attempt, and ask for help when you get stuck

Comment: Sorry about this, but my phone did not upload the picture.

Comment: Basically, I tried to create a macro, using name manager: Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="FTE_Headofsecurityandrevprotection_18", _
        RefersToR1C1:="='Job Title FTEs'!R36C22:R36C34"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("FTE_Headofsecurityandrevprotection_18").Comment = "

Comment: Do you need sheet-aware or workbook-aware names?

Comment: Sheet-aware please.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really confusing.

But I guess what you want is a simple function which names a specific range.

Try to use **Range.name**, i.e:

```
mySheet.columns("V:AH").name = "myColumns"
```

Yet, to use it:

```
mysheet.range("myColumns").select
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Basically I would like to create a macro that assigns a name to a range of cells, using name manager. The names that name manager needs to create are in column U and the range of data that name manager needs to use are from column U to column AH. Please consider that name manager needs to be used for the next available cell in column U. Thanks